# Reflexivity of intersection of two $L^p$ space

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, lp-spaces, reflexive-space

Q:Prove that the linear space $L^{p_1}\cap L^{p_2}$ $(p_1\neq p_2)$ with norm defined by
$$\|f\|_{L^{p_1}\cap L^{p_2}}=\|f\|_{L^{p_1}}+\|f\|_{L^{p_2}}$$
is a reflexive Banach space.

I've tried several ways to prove the reflexivity. Such as proving it's a closed subspace of $L^{p_1}$ $(/L^{p_2})$, proving it is a uniformly convex space but all failed. But it seems really complicated to prove directly that it is reflexive. Can someone show a way for me?
Thanks for your help!

Comment: What is the set of bounded linear functionals on this space?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possibility is to use a different/equivalent norm on $L^{p_1} \cap L^{p_2}$ which is uniformly convex, e.g.
$$\|f\|_{L^{p_1} \cap L^{p_2}}^* = \sqrt{\|f\|_{L^{p_1}}^2 + \|f\|_{L^{p_2}}^2}.$$

Comment: Why the space with this norm is uniformly convex?I found the same problem when proving this as proving the one in the question.

Comment: See Thm. 1 in Clarkson's work on uniformly spaces: http://www.ams.org/tran/1936-040-03/S0002-9947-1936-1501880-4/S0002-9947-1936-1501880-4.pdf. The proof can be adopted to the situation at hand.

Answer (score 2):

Products and closed subspaces are easily seen to be reflexive again and $L^p \cap L^q$ is isomorphic to $\lbrace (f,g)\in L^p \times L^q: f=g\rbrace$. To have this subspace closed you need just some Hausdorff topological space which contains both factors.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand your mean clearly.You mean take the product as the total space and the consider the target space subspace of it?Or just to find a more proper Hausdoff space such that the condition satisfies?But maybe it is not so easy to find such a well-behaved space.

Comment: You could take the space of all neasurable functions with convergence in measure.