# Uniform Convexity of $L^{p_1} \cap L^{p_2}$ with Maximum Norm

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

I am considering the space $E=L^{p_1}(\mathbb{R}) \cap L^{p_2}(\mathbb{R}), p_1,p_2 \in (1,\infty)$ with norm $\|f\|_E=\max\{\|f\|_{p_1}, \|f\|_{p_2}\}$. I have proven it is a Banach space and I want to prove it is reflexive using uniform convexity. Is it true that the norm $\|.\|_E$ is uniformly convex?

Comment: You may find [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1493550/reflexivity-of-intersection-of-two-lp-space) MSE post useful.

Comment: @JWP_HTX so is it also equivalent to $\sqrt{\|f\|_{p_1}+\|f\|_{p_2}}$? Is the proof similar to proving all norms in finite-dimensional space are equivalent?

Comment: yes, the equivalence of these norms on $E$ can be exactly like this

Comment: @daw Thank you!